# Difference between 진실 and 성실?

Tags: word-usage

진실 sincerity (towards person)

성실 sincerity, devotion (towards work\hobby\mission, etc)

Am I correct? If not, can u please explain the difference in nuances?

Comment: 진실 = truth 진실하다 = to be truthful 성실 = diligent and hardworking

Comment: @Coconut thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

성실 is diligent.

진실 is a bit more complex. It means sincere, honest, truth, etc.

Examples:

"그것은 진실이야." => It is a truth.

"그는 진실한 사람이야." => He is a truthful person. In other words, he doesn't lie.

"진실로 말하는데" => Speaking honestly